# WP_Query ordered by custom field that is a date string?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, order

Each of my posts have a single custom field that is a string of a date (not the date of the post). Instead of my theme's current query, which orders by published date, I want to order by this custom field date. How can I change this query (the theme's query) to instead use my custom field (a string representation of a date)?

```
$timeline_query = new WP_Query(array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
));
```

Answer (score 4):

The [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) page on the Codex has a section on [Order & Orderby Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

If you want to order the query by a custom field you should add `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` **AND** you must also specify the custom field (called `your_date_field` in the above example) using the `meta_key` key in the query.

```
$timeline_query = new WP_Query(array( 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'your_date_field' 
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a note for those using the HTML5 type="date" field, the format is recorded in yyyy-mm-dd. I was using 'orderby' => 'meta_value-num' because I thought the date was numeric, and didn't get why the order was off. Then I saw this thread and used 'meta_value' instead and it worked!

NOTE I wanted to add this as a comment to RRikesh's answer, but can't comment because my account doesn't have a high enough reputation yet, so I had to add a new answer.